# strings one after the other in c : "...""...", as if they were concatenate

Tags: c, string, concatenation, printf

I work on a c code that was not written by me, and there is lots of fprintf calls like this :

```
fprintf(file, "blabla1""blabla2%s""blabla3", mystring);
```

I had never seen that we could put several strings in the second argument of fprintf, is this a sort of concatenation ? Or is this a feature of fprintf ? If so, the specification of fprintf does not mention it ?

Answer (score 3):

This is feature of string literals, they will be concatated if they are adjacent. If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.5` *String literals paragraph 4* says:

> In translation phase 6, **the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of
>   adjacent character and wide string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte
>   character sequence.** If any of the tokens are wide string literal tokens, the resulting
>   multibyte character sequence is treated as a wide string literal; otherwise, it is treated as a character string literal.

As Lundin points out a simpler quote can be found in section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases paragraph 6*:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Comment: "Translation phase 6" is found at C11 5.1.1.2/6: `Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.`

Comment: @Lundin Huh, that is a more straight forward quote, thanks for pointing it out, same quote exists in C99 as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a feature of `fprintf()`, that would be impossible (how would you implement such a function yourself?) since `fprintf()` is just a standard function with no extra magic done by the compiler.

It's a feature of C's syntax: adjacent string literals are treated as a single literal by just concatenating them together.

It's very useful together with the [preprocessor's stringification support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer each question in turn.

- *is this a sort of concatenation ?*

You hit the nail on the head. Yes indeed.

- *Or is this a feature of fprintf ?*

Nope, just part of C syntax.

- *If so, the specification of fprintf does not mention it ?*

That isn't actually a question, despite the punctuation, but you're probably correct that the fprintf specification does not mention this type of concatenation, and that's because it's because it's part of the language, not the specific function.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, there is only one format code:  `"%s"`.  It accepts the value contained in mystring,  so the result will be:  "blablablabla2_contents of mystring_blabla3"

Yes, this is legal code.  I am not sure why someone would do this though.